# Is it possible to travel across Turkey from the northeast corner to the southwest corner in 5 days/

Tags: public-transport, turkey, georgia-country, greece

I will start from Georgia. Then I enter Turkey somewhere and I would like to travel across the country somehow (no plan yet). The last stop in Turkey might be marmaris. Anyway, I have to go to the Rhodes island and from there to the Crete island.

I think I have 5-6 days in Turkey.

Is the time ample?

I cannot drive.

Comment: Take the car and drive from one point to another.  Should take you no more then a day or 2.  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I cannot drive.

Comment: Then can you edit the question add the restrictions placed on this journey?  Otherwise it's too broad and unclear.

Comment: should be fairly easy by bus/train. You can even stay in one or two cities each day.

Answer (score 3):

This is not rocket science: It's ample for getting from one end to the other. It's not if you have to use public transport and also want to be a tourist.

But, it's easily doable. Long distance bus transport is very good in Turkey.

Answer (score 1):

I've traveled in Eastern Turkey last summer and also entered Turkey from Georgia.

In Batumi you need to take the mini bus at Tbilisi Square. (https://goo.gl/maps/igPYhibW1xP2)

You need to find the bus that goes to Sarpi (the border town). You 'll be dropped at the border office.

Go through the border control.

On the other side taxis will take you to Hopa. The first city in Turkey from where you can start your travel by bus through Turkey.

I spent two weeks traveling in Eastern Turkey finishing in Capadocia and from where I took a final bus to Istanbul.

You can see my photos of every day of this trip here: http://thdk.be/travel/eastern-turkey/

I hope this information is helpful to you.